# How to map GPS coordinates on the map I made?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I want to know how to mapping GPS coordinate on the map what i made in Android.

So, I want to display the GPS coordinates on my own 3D map. Not using Google map.

I want to create my own map application by creating a map of the market or famous streets.

I can not find any related technology by Googleing because I am not good at English.

To summarize the point of my question,

1. Can i create my own map application like I said?
2. If it is possible, Is it too hard? (I am a beginner developer.)
3. Please let me know any related open source or blog or tech doc.

Answer (score 0):

we can able to create custom maps.
**Refer this following Link to create a custom map**
**https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-map-in-power-map-e4b00d30-c8c0-4a14-ba2b-ac3316a2eb94**